# is it possible to detect color around white color in Android?

Tags: android, opencv, color-detection

I am new in OpenCV.

i want to detect green,blue and red color that is around bright white color and draw the rectangle of contours.

i have tried with `Core.inRange` method but it giving me one specific color:

```
 List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();  
 Mat light = new Mat();  
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, light, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
        Core.inRange(light, new Scalar(0, 0, 250), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), light);
        Imgproc.findContours(light, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0, 0));
        Rect rect = null; //= Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
        double maxVal = 0;    
        for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {               
                     double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));    
                    if (maxVal < contourArea) {
                        maxVal = contourArea;
                        rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(contourIdx));
                    }

                }
```

How can i do this?

Thank you !

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so we can see where you went wrong---this is absolutely possible using `inRange()`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds  Please check updated question, i have added code that is currently giving me bright white color in output, now i want to detect white color that is around red, green or blue color ! please help ! Thanks

Comment: You're filtering each of the blue, green, and red channels and saying "I am allowing blue values between (min, max), green values between (min, max), and red values between (min, max)". The first `Scalar()` is (blue min, green min, red min) and the second is (blue max, green max, red max). So your current code is *only* pulling areas which have (very) high red values---between 250 and 255---and those pixels must also have 0 blue or green components. In other words you're only selecting pixels with BGR values (0,0,250), (0,0,251), ..., (0,0,255).

Comment: If you want *white* pixels, they have high values in all three channels, so your threshold values (`Scalar()`s) need to be like (220, 220, 220) and (255, 255, 255) or similar.